# Table border-collapse + transform cause weird bug

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

Is this a bug?

JSFiddle: please check comment (I was not able to add jsfiddle link to this post, weird)

On Chrome:

[image]

On Firefox:

[image]

What I expected (I have to photoshop this ):

[image]

Please help

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n05usexd/1/